# I need to get all MultipartFile objects from HTTP request in Map<String, MultipartFile> form in Spring REST app

Tags: java, spring, http, xmlhttprequest, spring-rest

When I use the `@RequestBody` annotation, it throws an exception. So I had to use `@RequestParam`, but it works only for 1 parameter, but it's inconvenient if I have more files. I need an annotation that solves it.

```
@PostMapping("/products/{id}/img")
public void setProductImgs(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam(name = "img") MultipartFile fd) throws IOException {

    String dir = "C:\\Projects\\JavaProjects\\project\\src\\main\\resources\\static\\img\\product-" + id + "\\";

    File directory = new File(dir);

    if(directory.exists())
        FileUtils.cleanDirectory(directory);
    else
        directory.mkdir();

    String type = fd.getOriginalFilename().split("\\.")[1];

    fd.transferTo(new File(dir + "0." + type));
}
```

Comment: `@RequestPart MultipartFile[] files` if you send multiple files in the same request

Comment: Ok. But the array length is always 0.

Comment: You might need to add `consumes=MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE` in your `@PostMapping`. If it doesn't work, please add how you send your request.

Comment: It is fine. I just changed to @RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> and it works.